# Improving PostgreSQL full-text search

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to implement a basic full-text search in Postgres. And I have some questions about **materialized view** and **index** to improving search:

1. I use a materialized view to store search data in one column called document (data type: tsvector). I have about 1000 records and when I try some queries with or without an index, the search time is equivalent.

   So Do I need to use an Index on this view?

   And what type of Index is better, GIN or GIST? (I have 1-2 more records each day and rarely update)
2. When a record was inserted, I need to REFRESH materialized view.

   If I use INDEX, do I need REINDEX?

   When the view refreshing, queries using it must be waiting until the refresh has been completed. How to solve it?

Edit:

- I create materialized view with command:

  ```
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW search_index AS 
  SELECT p.id AS id, p.title AS title, p.published_at as published_at, u.name AS author, 
         setweight(to_tsvector('simple', unaccent(p.title)), 'A') ||     
         setweight(to_tsvector('simple', unaccent(p.content)), 'B') || 
         setweight(to_tsvector('simple', unaccent(u.name)), 'C') AS document
  FROM posts AS p
  JOIN users AS u ON p.created_by = u.id
  ```
- Search query (example with key 'framework'):

  ```
  SELECT * FROM search_index
  WHERE document @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'framework')
  ORDER BY published_at DESC
  ```
- Create index:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX idx_fts_search ON search_index USING GIN(document);
  ```

=> Search times about 185ms (167 rows) even use Index or not.

- When use **Explain** command (I don't understand this command)

  Without Index

  [image]

  With Index

  [image]

Comment: So how do your queries look like? You can create full text indexes using GIN: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-tables.html

Comment: My query like this: SELECT document FROM search_index
WHERE document @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'keyword'). I create text indexes using GIN but search times does not decrease. (search_index is materialized view)

Comment: Post the complete table definition, index definition and the output of `explain (analyze, verbose) for your query` [**Edit your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35695066/edit) don't post code in comments

Comment: I have the same issue on pg table not view, did you find a solution to Postgres not using full text index ?